# Android ListView when get data

Tags: android, multithreading, listview

I would like to upload with data my listview However I get my data from the internet but it takes a bit time. So I have to wait for it. How can I give the datas to my listview . Ofcourse It comes into threads and I dont know how to handle this? Im using SimpleAdapter. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use **AsyncTask** to populate the data from internet to **ListView**.

More about `AsyncTask` here

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

**onPreExecute**

show a progress dialoge.

**doInBackground**

fetch data from internet

**onPostExecute**

populate the **ListView**